# TypeError is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I really don't understand why:

```
var ds= ds || {};
ds.Buynow = function ($parameters) {
    var parameters = {
        server_url: null,
        redirect_url: null
    };

    //buynow
    var addBuynowButtonsHandler = function () {
        [..stuff..]
    };

    var init = function () {
        $.extend(parameters, $parameters);
        addBuynowButtonsHandler();
    };

    init();
};

ds.Raffle = function ($parameters) {
    var parameters = {
        server_url: null,
        redirect_url: null,
        info_url: null
    };

    //ruffle
    var addRaffleButtonsHandler = function () {
        [...stuff...]
    };

    var init = function () {
        $.extend(parameters, $parameters);
        addRaffleButtonsHandler();
    };

    init();
};
```

Now calling:

```
new ds.Raffle({...]);
```

gives no error and everything works fine. Instead calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        new ds.Buynow({
            [..]
        });
    });
</script>
```

gives the error `TypeError: ds.Buynow is not a constructor`
I've also checked elsewhere and saw that this error can be caused by a ds.Buynow object defined somewhere else but I've tried a `console.log(ds.Buynow)` just before the new declaration and it give me `undefined`. Also, changing name to Buynow to something else doesn't affect the error. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Your code works fine. If you have an issue, post code that actually demonstrates it. However, since you've determined that `Buynow` is `undefined`, but changing the name doesn't produce the error, seems pretty clear that something is overwriting it.

Comment: You'll need to post the code that's causing the error and highlight the line of the fault.

Comment: @ManoDestra I've edited, there's not really much to add. The error is in the `new ds.Buynow` row

Comment: @squint the error is in the first declaration row, how can i check if something is overwriting it?

Comment: You check via laborious examination of your code. You can try searches of your code files `Buynow` in hopes of finding the line that is breaking things. You can also insert `console.log(ds.Buynow)` at various points in your code to see if you can narrow down the location of the problem. Ultimately, it just takes this sort of tedious work to track down bugs like this.

Comment: Also, use a linter like [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org) or [`JSHint`](http://jshint.com) to see if there are any common mistakes made anywhere that could cause this issue or others.

Comment: I've found out that the error seems only in firefox, i've tried it in chrome and it works.

Comment: Did you define ds at all? I get an error because you haven't defined ds. I add `var ds = {};` above your constructor functions and it works fine. In fact, I get the same error in Chrome.

Comment: Yep sorry, i've defined ds, i'll edit the code